# Concatenate two AVI files WITHOUT ffmpeg. Using NodeJS or other framework

Tags: node.js, algorithm, video, concatenation, avi

Does anyone know how to concatenate two or more AVI files, "manually", which means by reading the files and writing the "concatenated" bytes to another one ? And without any third library like FFMPEG.

The final purpose of this algorithm is to make an AVI stream with nodejs from multiple files created on the fly on the server. But if you have an explanation without NodeJs, it would help me to understand the structure of the AVI file.

I almost managed to do it in NodeJs. 
First, i write a faked header, with "Content-Type: video/avi" and no length specification, and then i just concatenate the bytes from the multiple AVI files. It works, and VLC can read the stream even though i forgot to remove the headers from the multiple AVI files.

BUT the strange thing is that i need to cut the last bytes of each files (and not the header!), so that VLC does not consider the file to be finished, and keeps the connection opened till i add the next AVI chunk.

And from time to time, after 3 or 4 minutes of playing, VLC stops reading my stream, but there is no specific case that i can explain to you to reproduce this.

Are there rules about the end bytes of an AVI file ? maybe the way i cut the end of my chunks can trigger the end of the reading sometimes ?

I choose arbitrarily to cut the 1024*32 last bytes of each AVI file, just because it works but i know it's not the best way

Comment: Avi is just a container. There is no possible solution without reencoding, if those input-avis are different somehow (resolution, number of audio-tracks and most important: different codecs...). So much more information is needed what exactly you want to concatenate and why you don't want to use ffmpeg.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I cannot use ffmpeg because it would require the video files to be created before i launch the command. ffmpeg needs the file to exist on the disk. I need to generate a video file on a server with files created on the fly, and put them on a stream that is constantly read by a client. 
I know i could use playlist with name pipes and so on, but it works only on mac and linux, because windows cant handle that kind of files.
Or do you know a simpler video format than AVI, that i could easily manipulate byte per byte ?

Comment: and to add some precisions, i have control on the original AVI files so i can make them exactly with same duration and number of tracks and codecs. Only the content is different

Comment: I don't think that is a good approach of yours, but [this](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate) might help. If you stick to transport-streams, you can byte-wise append. Look at the *Concat protocol**. This could be done without ffmpeg.

Comment: Have you had a look at [fluent ffmpeg](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg)? You can pass streams to it from nodejs and run ffmpeg commands on the streams - so in theory you could read the avi files into stream objs and just pass the streams to fluent ffmpeg without writing them to disk.

Comment: Hi, these looks like better ways to go. I will try it. Thanks !